# Nuxt3 global time variable for front-end

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a list of shops on my website, which have working hours. I want to show a label that a shop is closed when it's closed and hide it when it's opened. I would like to check the opening state every second.

What I came up with is just creating such a file:

```
// now.ts

import { ref } from 'vue'

export const now = ref(new Date())

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  now.value = new Date()
}, 1000) // update now every second
```

And then using the `now` variable in computed properties to force updates. Something like:

```
const isWorking = computed(() => {
   now.value // to force recompute every second
   return isShopWorking(shop)
})
```

But it initiates the `now` variable server-side, it looks hacky and overall does not seem the right approach.

What is the proper way to do it, so that there is one global `now` variable created on the front-end and updated every second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using composables:

- interval composable (https://vueuse.org/shared/useIntervalFn/)
- custom composable for checking working state each 1 second

```
import { useIntervalFn } from '@vueuse/core'

export const useIsWorking = (shop) => {
  function calculateIsWorking() {
    // ... define now
    return now >= shop.openTime && now <= shop.closeTime
  }

  const isWorking = ref(calculateIsWorking())

  useIntervalFn(() => {
    isWorking.value = calculateIsWorking()
  }, 1000)

  return readonly(isWorking)
}
```